# Очень упорный Защитник Windows

Tags: windows, windows-10, defender

Имеем: Windows 10. Буквально при каждой перегрузке Защитник выносит предупреждение о проблемах, и указывает на файл (если важно — образ Hiren Boot) с WindowsLoader.exe где-то внутри, как на содержащий страшную угрозу - HackTool:Win23/Keygen.

При этом указывает второй строкой

> 10.06.2023 18:18 (Активно)

Сегодня, напомню, уже 21, сам файл сначала был внесен в исключения, потом туда же была внесена вся папка, потом файл запакован в rar с паролем — т.е. такого файла, как он пишет, просто нет на диске! - ничего не помогает. Загрузка, сообщение...

Разрешал на устройстве, помещал в карантин, удалял - до лампочки.

Запускаю быструю проверку - опять то же самое: обнаружены угрозы от 10 июня...

Спасите! Как ему мозги вправить, чтоб он понял, что угрозы давно нет?

Comment: Я на компы клиентов ставлю Kaspersky Free. С ним проще договориться о кейгенах. И штатный защитник винды не вмешивается. Есть строка на павершелле, которая в принципе отрубает службу. Более детально - хз, не использую.

Comment: @donRumata Увы, это не решение вопроса...

Comment: Ну а строку `windows defender whitelist` ты конечно же гуглил и не помогло? Я просто настройку именно через пошик.

Comment: Нет, помогло совсем другое...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Чтобы стереть историю в такой ситуации, надо очистить каталог

```
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows Defender\Scans\History\Service
```

Как ни странно, этот совет + полное сканирование компьютера после этого помогло.